# @RunWith causes Maven to ignore my Test running with my own runner

Tags: java, maven-2, junit, surefire

I am moving from using only Intellij to manage my build system to Intellij/Maven.  When I run my integration test "MapSimulationTest" with my own runner via @RunWith(KmlParameterizedRunner.class) Intellij correctly handles the situation, the directory specified by the system property "user.dir" is scanned for .kml files and each is tested.

The problem seems to be that Surefire ignores @RunWith, any suggestions?

Here is what the maven log shows...

> -------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
>   ------------------------------------------------------- Running
>   com.tqicorp.guru.MapSimulationTest
>   Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0,
>   Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.061 sec

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if surefire ignores @RunWith altogether.

Comment: I'm suffering from the same problem. I am using @RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)

Comment: mdma: Note that 'mvn site' no longer works in maven 3.0. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584346/how-do-i-generate-site-with-mvn-sitesite

Answer (score 2):

I'm using surefire and @RunWith with the [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html) test runner, and it is working fine with maven 2.2.1.

To track down the problem, you could try creating a simple Junit test using the @Test annotation, rather than the old style testXXX method. Run "mvn test" and see if your test is being executed. If it is, that will rule out any possibility of an old junit in your path. If it's not being executed, then run "mvn site", and search the dependencies report for junit, and check the version. It's amazing how easy unwanted versions can creep in!

Answer (score 2):

Try verifying you are using the latest version of the maven-surefire-plugin; I have been burned in the past by bugs with *my* surefire uasge until I relized these bugs had been fixed in a newer version of the plugin and I simply had to update.

Answer (score 1):

You may already be doing it, but this can happen if your maven dependency is using old junit version (3.x) instead of junit 4.x where these annotations are respected. 
Check your pom.xml to see if the right junit version is the articfact

Comment: This is not the case, I have excluded junit and junit-dep in libraries that have an older version of JUnit as a transient dependency (ie: jmock).

Answer (score 1):

This might happen if you have TestNG dependency. Remove dependency and Maven will search for @org.junit.Test annotations in your classes, if TestNG dependency present then Maven search for @org.testng.annotations.Test annotation.

Comment: Thanks so much! I know this is 4 years later, but this just fixed an issue I've had for hours.