# How do I generate site with mvn site:site?

Tags: java, maven-3

I want to generate a site with mvn, but I cannot configure it to generate `index.html`.

I can ran different reports like:

```
$ mvn javadoc:javadoc      # generates target/site/apidocs
$ mvn cobertura:cobertura  # generates target/site/cobertura
```

but

```
$ mvn site:site
```

doesn't generate anything. What I want is for `mvn site:site` to automatically generate reports and site in `target/site`. I don't need to deploy it yet.

For reference [this](http://pastie.org/private/xwzfb3numkhpozbngjscg) is my pom.xml. I also added `src/site/site.xml`, but the results were similar.

Comment: your pom looks fine. the site is generated at target/site.

Comment: @Salandur: Unfortunately only two directories are added in `target/`: `target/images/` and `target/site`. No `index.html`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

mvn site is no longer available/working in Maven 3 IIRC

See:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-SiteandReporting

Comment: Any alternative I should look into?