# JUNIT custom runner does not recognized from Maven test goal

Tags: java, junit, maven

I have custom runner of JUNIT, run with annotation:
@RunWith(SomeClass.class)

When running maven goal test it does not run it.
What should be done? is it configurable?

Comment: Just in case, are you sure you don't have TestNG on your classpath? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232853/how-to-execute-junit-and-testng-tests-in-same-project-using-maven-surefire-plugin

Comment: Is your JUnit executed without @RunWith when you run mvn test?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717902/runwith-causes-maven-to-ignore-my-test-running-with-my-own-runner?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the problem isn't related to @RunWith; otherwise you should at least get an error. Does the test class match one of Maven's (Surefire's) naming patterns for test classes (e.g. **/*Test.java)?

Comment: Thanks, i change the file name :)